# JSON contact information based on selected country (dropdown & map)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, svg

I have a dropdown that has a list of countries where a client operates.

I also have a JSON file with the following (dummy info, obviously):

```
[
    {
        title: "Malaysia",
        lineOne: "Address one",
        lineTwo: "Address two,",
        lineThree: "Address three,",
        lineFour: "Address four,",
        postCode: "AA1 1AA",
        email: "email@address.com",
        tel: "+44 1234 567 890",
        mob: "",
        name: "Name McName",
        lat: 00.000000,
        lng: -00.000000
    },
    {
        title: "USA",
        lineOne: "Address one",
        lineTwo: "Address two,",
        lineThree: "Address three,",
        lineFour: "Address four,",
        postCode: "AA1 1AA",
        email: "email@address.com",
        tel: "+44 1234 567 890",
        mob: "",
        name: "Name McName",
        lat: 00.000000,
        lng: -00.000000
    },
]
```

So the issue that I'm facing is that when someone selects a country, JS iterates through the JSON file and generates a contact info block in the front end for every item where the 'title' matches the country in the data-country tag in the option for that country.

I'm relatively new to working with JSON and all the tutorials I've found are close, but not quite what I need. Is anyone able to give me a bit of guidance where to look or help me directly?

p.s. that there is also an SVG map where the available countries have a custom class that will have to update with the country selected in the dropdown and vice versa but I thought it would be easier to get one working first then worry about the map once the dropdown is working

Sorry if this isn't very clear, but as mentioned, I'm pretty fresh to this sort of JS.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Amcharts.com has very good js maps and plenty of tutorials.  This can actually get pretty complicated.  Particularly map integration.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I think it'll be easier to get the dropdown sorted, but I am worried that the map integration could need some foundation work during the dropdown JS stuff instead of just bolting it on at the end.